# How to route packets from Wi-Fi to Ethernet on OSX?

Tags: networking, macos, routing

I have a trouble, configuring a home network.

Here is how my devices are connected together:

Internet
    ↕
Wi-Fi Router ↔ MacBook
    ↕
 iMac ←ethernet cable→ Synology NAS

I have no ability to plugin NAS right into the Wi-Fi router.

The problem is that MacBook does not see NAS, because they are in different networks — I configured Wi-Fi Router to serve 192.168.10.0/24 addresses, and configured iMac's ethernet connection to use 192.168.20/24 network.

Is there a way to setup route from MacBook to the NAS?

Comment: why did you put them on different subnets? Is the "router" actually a router or just an access point?

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the `WiFi<-> Ethernet` part and just think about it as "How can I **route** traffic on a iMac?".

For that you need add a routing table entry on the iMac. Assuming the iMac runs OS X you can just search on OS X and routing and you will find posts like [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/450493/changing-routing-on-mac-with-two-ethernet-ports/450499#comment524921_450499).

If you feel that it lack background information then I suggest reading [This post on SE: SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).

---

An other option (One which allows you to access the Synology NAS when the iMac is turned off) would be to just add a switch.

```
 Internet
    ↕
Wi-Fi Router 
    ↕
 SWITCH   
    |
    | → Synology NAS
    |
    | → MacBook
    |
    | → iMac
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just add a static route on your macbook. If you understand the basics of a network this is straight forward and you won't need to change your network or add devices.

Principle of adding a static route from your macbook is to tell it how to reach the NAS applicance/box.

Check this article below for a better description and walkthrough

[http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060329085850170](http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/)http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060329085850170

http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/