# Windows 7 Set metric to use 2 different network interfaces at the same time

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan, routing

I'm looking for a way to use at the same time wired and wireless interfaces.

**My situation:**

- 1 Gbit ethernet interface (10.100.x.x)
- 1 WiFi 802.11 b/g/n interface (192.168.x.x)
- The PC is part of a domain (10.100.x.x) and I logon using a LDAP user.

**I want to use the Ethernet interface to connect to the domain and navigate through LAN, but every time I need to access the internet, I want to use the WiFi.**

The Ethernet interface is configured for the domain, so there's a DHCP that assigns every setting, from PC IP address to default gateway IP and DNS.

I tried almost everything...

1. "Advanced settings" on "Network Connection Panel" to change the
   interfaces order.
2. Route table to adjust interfaces and gateways metrics.
3. "Network Adapter Advanced Settings" to uncheck the automatic metric
   and set a manual value.

When both my interfaces are activated this is my `Route table`:

```
IPv4 Tabella route
===========================================================================
Route attive:
     Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.100.1.1      10.100.1.55    276
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.10.1   192.168.10.208    281
       10.100.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.100.1.55    276
      10.100.1.55  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    276
     10.100.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
   192.168.10.208  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
   192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
    192.168.184.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
    192.168.184.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
  192.168.184.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
    192.168.222.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
    192.168.222.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
  192.168.222.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.100.1.55    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
===========================================================================
Route permanenti:
  Nessuna
```

The best I was able to obtain was to set a manual metric value to the Ethernet interface so the metric of gateway increased till a value greater than the WiFi gateway. This way lead me to gain access to the Internet by the WiFi gateway (as I wanted) **BUT** I loose my network connections access so I cannot access my domain resources (server, shares, printers...).

Using the procedure described above I finally have this `Route table`:

```
IPv4 Tabella route
===========================================================================
Route attive:
     Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.100.1.1      10.100.1.55    356
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.10.1   192.168.10.208    281
       10.100.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.100.1.55    356
      10.100.1.55  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    356
     10.100.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    356
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
   192.168.10.208  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
   192.168.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
    192.168.184.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
    192.168.184.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
  192.168.184.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
    192.168.222.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
    192.168.222.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
  192.168.222.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.100.1.55    356
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.184.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.100.1.55    356
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.10.208    281
===========================================================================
Route permanenti:
  Nessuna
```

Here the WiFi gateway (192.168.x.x) has lower metrics than ethernet one, so I can go to the WAN with that but I cannot access my network resources anymore.
It seems that with that route table, every LAN connection tries to pass through WiFi interface.
I tried to change and delete the `0.0.0.0    0.0.0.0    10.100.1.1    10.100.1.55    276` route but nothing appened...

Comment: Why are you trying to use metrics? Why not set a route to (10.100.x.x/16) via the wired NIC and the only default gateway via wireless?

Comment: Regarding dual network setup, (one for Internet, one for corporate/work), also see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/450493/changing-routing-on-mac-with-two-ethernet-ports. (Same network principles apply to windows as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands:

`route delete 0.0.0.0 10.100.1.1`

`route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.100.1.1`

If that works, put them in a batch file in your StartUp folder to automatically run every time you log in.  This should do the job.

Comment: There's no `route 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.0` in my route tables, but I think you probably mean `route delete 0.0.0.0 10.100.1.1`... anyway I already tried to delete that route and add the other you suggest but it didn't work.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what do you mean?  Did you get an error message from the correctly-specified `route delete` command?  Did the routing table change in any way as a result?

Comment: The routing table has changed according to my commands but when I open the browser and try to go to WAN (any website) I'm asked to connect to the domain proxy server with my user/pwd, so I understand that the traffic is going out through my 10.100.x.x ethernet. I already checked the browser Internet Options and there's nothing wrong, indeed if I disable the 10.10.x.x ethernet interface and try to go out with the same browser and the same configuration, it works and the traffic go out with 192.160.x.x WiFi interface without asking proxy authentication.